# vector plus unique_ptr to an object, memory not freed?

Tags: c++, vector, unique-ptr

So, I'm trying to use vectors together with smart pointers to have easier time with memory management, and... well, I'm having problems.
That's the (greatly shortened) version of my code:

bulletManager.h:

```
class BulletManager
{
    public:
        BulletManager();
        virtual ~BulletManager();

        void AddBullet(int type, double x, double y, double vx, double vy);
        void EraseAllBullets();
    protected:
    private:
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Bullet>> bullets;
};
```

bulletManager.cpp:

```
BulletManager::BulletManager()
{
    bullets.reserve(50000);
}
void BulletManager::AddBullet(int type, double x, double y, double vx, double vy)
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) bullets.push_back(std::unique_ptr<BasicBullet>(new BasicBullet(type, x, y, vx, vy)));
}
void BulletManager::EraseAllBullets()
{
    bullets.clear();
}
```

The BasicBullet class is a subclass of the abstract Bullet class.
To have easier time seeing the memory usage changes, I've made the AddBullet functions generate 1000 objects and also put "char tab[10000]" in the bullet class.

Now, what happens (according to the Task Manager) is:

- Calling AddBullet once -> memory usage increases slightly
- Calling EraseAllBullets after that -> memory usage doesn't drop at all!
- Calling AddBullet a couple of times -> significant memory usage increase
- Calling EraseAllBullets after that -> most memory is freed, but not all!

The effect isn't very big and seems to slow down - the program starts with 10MB of RAM usage and after using only these two functions for a while, with each vector clear the memory usage drops only to 15-20MB.

Am I doing something wrong? Even if that's supposed to happen, I would still prefer if I was able to free all memory that I've allocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't rely on task manager to tell you how much memory your application has allocated/available. When you free the memory it may well be reclaimed by a pool within the C++ runtime for later reuse by your application rather than returned to the OS.

Comment: If that's Windows memory management thing and not my fault, I'm already happy. This thing has been giving me a headache for the past few hours.
So the only good way to reliably check for actual leaks is to use a profiler?

Comment: Basically. Profilers are made specifically for this use-case. Try testing with Valgrind, if you are able to compile your code on a Unix machine.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing nothing wrong, you just have the wrong assumptions.

The behaviour you're observing can come from two totally different things:

- `std::vector::clear()` is only supposed to delete the objects contained in the vector, not to actually release the memory of the vector itself. As [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) puts it: "*Many implementations will not release allocated memory after a call to `clear()`, effectively leaving the `capacity()` of the vector unchanged.*" **You can work around this particular issue** by using `std::vector<...>().swap(vectorToClear);` instead of `clear()`: that swaps a new temporary, empty vector with yours, effectively releasing all the memory yours uses.
- C++'s `delete` operator does not necessarily return the memory to the system. It just frees the memory so that it is usable again by `new`, again there is no requirement that the system gets the memory back. There is no workaround to that behaviour, it depends on your runtime (ie. compiler).

Comment: I'm not expecting the vector to release its own memory - notice that I've used bullets.reserve(50000); at the very beginning. I only expect it to get rid of the smart pointers so they will take care of deleting the objects themselves.

I didn't know about the second part, though. Thanks!

Comment: From the code & explanation you posted it wasn't clear to me what you really expected (yup, I've had a hard day), so I thought I'd still mention the first point just in case. :) But yeah the second point is very important to understand so that you don't get any surprise.